how to resolve circular reference error with AbstactMongoClientConfiguration in Spring Boot
I am getting an error that indicates a cyclical reference between the MappingMongoConverter and mongoConverter. How do i resolve this?
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.baeldung.repository")
public class MongoDBConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private MappingMongoConverter mongoConverter;

    @Bean
    public GridFsTemplate gridFsTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new GridFsTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mongoConverter);}

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return null;
    }
}

